# how to Use google_chart gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems, google-visualization

I am trying to represent data using the [google_charts](http://rubygems.org/gems/google_charts) gem but it does not seem to work for me i copied the sample code in the rdoc and tried it, i keep getting the error `undefined method pie_chart for #<#<Class:0xa8241b4>:0xa828a0c>`

```
  <% pie_chart( [ [:eggs, 3], [:bacon, 1] ], { :height => 300, :is3D => true }, { :id => "breakfastChart" } ) do |c| -%>
    <% c.title "breakfast" %>

    <% c.label "ingredient", :first %>
    <% c.value "amount", :last %>
  <% end -%>
```

but if i try it this way i keep getting the same error message.

```
  <% Googlecharts.pie_chart( [ [:eggs, 3], [:bacon, 1] ], { :height => 300, :is3D => true }, { :id => "breakfastChart" } ) do |c| -%>
    <% c.title "breakfast" %>

    <% c.label "ingredient", :first %>
    <% c.value "amount", :last %>
  <% end -%>
```

I admit i am using this gem for the first time because it is the most recent of them all i usually use the [googlecharts](http://rubygems.org/gems/googlecharts) gem and it works fine for me but do not want to use it cos it uses urls for the chart and it is not frequently maintained. So now i want to represent the following data in a bar chart with the following code sample in my song model

```
  # Return the percentage of responses that are yes.  Output is a whole integer.
  def percentage_yes
    return 0 if yes_count == 0

    ((yes_count.to_f / replies_count) * 100).to_i
  end

  # Return the percentage of responses that are no.  Output is a whole integer.
  def percentage_no
    return 0 if no_count == 0

    100 - percentage_yes
  end

  # Return a chart showing the yes/no breakdown of responses
  def chart_responses
    chart = GoogleChart.pie_400x150(["#{percentage_yes}% yes", percentage_yes], ["#{percentage_no}% no", percentage_no])
    chart.colors = ['BCDEA5', 'E6F9BC']
    return chart
  end
```

How can i use the google_charts gem to represent the `chart_responses` in a bar chart using this particular gem.